# handle spaces in the URL parameter using re_path

Tags: django, url-routing

I am passing 2 variables in the URL foo, bar. The variable bar has a multiple words with spaces between it. On the basis of foo and bar the content of the template is rendered. Whenever bar has a space in between the words my url handler gives a 404.

example: localhost/post/foo/ba r/
results in a 404

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('post/<slug:foo>/<slug:bar>/', post),
]
```

views.py

```
def post(request, foo, bar):
    query = Blog.objects.all().filter(category=foo, title=bar)
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html',
                  {'blog': query, 'cat': foo, 'tit': bar})
```

post.html

```
{% for i in blog %}
    {{ i.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you try logging the `foo` and `bar` before `query` ?

Comment: I don't understand, logging as in how? @Umair

Comment: try `print(foo) print(bar)` and check whats the output in console [assuming you're using python3]

Comment: I already am doing that in my actual code, this is just a stripped down version I've posted. My DB Model is setup this way that `bar` will contain multiple words and spaces in between them

Comment: What's being printed there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow spaces along with other characters using regex.

```
re_path(r'^post/(?P<foo>[\w|\W]+)/(?P<bar>[\w|\W]+)/$', post)
```

Comment: I am glad that it helped.